# RSA алгоритм. Проблема с modpow

Tags: c++, c, rsa

В функцию xsqrmodpow передаю значения str[i], e, m. str - string.
С небольшими числами работает хорошо, чем больше числа, тем больше вероятность неправильной работы модуля (e генерируется рандомно, но проверяется на взаимную простоту с фи(m)). Вроде бы функция предназначена для длинной арифметики и сбоев быть не должно. Например на вход подаю 'L' (76), 121, 10515066833. Возвращается 61470791.

[image: WolframAlpha]

Вольфрам выдает другое значение.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может заключаться ошибка?

```
uint64_t xsqrmodpow(uint64_t b, uint64_t X, uint64_t M)
uint64_t B = b;
uint64_t P = 1;

while (X != 0)
{
    if ((X & 1) == 1)
    {
        P = (P * B) % M;
    }
    B = (B * B) % M;
    X >>= 1;
}

return (uint64_t)P;
```

Comment: А что в имени вашей функции значит "sqr", кстати?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов exponentiation by squaring

Comment: *"Вроде бы функция предназначена для длинной арифметики и сбоев быть не должно."* - я не вижу у вас даже намека на длинную арифметику. `uint64_t` - это короткое число, а не длинное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что, поскольку `M` у вас порядка 10<sup>10</sup>, то в какой-то момент, например, `B` оказывается примерно той же величины. И его возведение в квадрат **приводит к переполнению**. Или умножение `P` на `B`, так как `P` тоже может оказаться больш*и*м одновременно с `B`. Т.е. работать оно будет корректно, пока `M` вписывается в `uint32_t`. Что вы и заметили - неверную работу при больших числах.